# Joomla 2.5 registering different kinds of users

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

Maybe this isn't the correct place to ask, but I asked this question on Joomla forums and did not get any answers. If someone can help me or at least point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate.

My question is: In a Joomla 2.5 website, I want to create two different kinds of forms for registering users. Maybe "registering" isn't the correct term. I want to create something like a very simple database which will hold records for two kinds of users:
    - one which will be interested in working in projects, so in this case the form will have more fields and specific details to fill
    - one which will be interested only in receiving newsletters from the site, and in this case only basic contact information will be required.

I did some research and found an extension named AcyMailing which can handle the newsletters for example, but I need to have all my potential users registered as Joomla users. I would like to avoid that if possible. If not, how can I differentiate the two kinds of users on registration, so the visitor can choose which option he wants and in this case, add more information to the registering process, if possible.

I'm not very experienced with Joomla, but since the site in question is already implemented using it, I don't have much choice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chronoforms.  Most definitely here would be a great use for their AWESOME free component.  Your forms can work as registration forms (should you desire that); or can also just be free standing forms that log the information filled out on them to your database which you can later use however you would like (i.e. compiling a mailing list or something of that sort).

The form wizard makes it almost bullet proof, then you can have a form for 1 type of user to fill out, and a form for a different user build different ways.

That will get you the data - in order to mass mail those people you'll need a way to extract their emails out of the database (or find an email component that will let you email based on certain fields in the database or what have you); but it's totally possible and would be easily done I think with 1 simple mySQL query on your database table created by chronoforms.

In terms of something that will solve your issue quickly and get you the info you're looking for in two separate ways - chronoforms will do that exactly.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer. I'll look in this Chronoforms.
But about saving the data on MySQL, for what I have read I need to use Joomla API to retrieve the data, right? Because I will not be the one running the site, so the actual administrators need to have some easy tool to retrieve this data I think.